# Shorter way to sum numbers?

Tags: python-2.7

This line is too long and rudimentary please teache me a better way that gives me the same outcome thanks

latitud = datos[0]+datos[1]+datos[2]+datos[3]+datos[4]+datos[5]+datos[6]+datos[7]

considering datos has long info in string because it receives over serial port from arduno so I want to sum up only until datos[7] and discard datos[8], datos[9] and so on thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that datos is a list containing numbers like [1,5,24,67,2]
so:

```
datos = [1,5,24,67,2]
print sum(datos[0:7])
```

edited to show only first 7, btw tnx Tolonen for edit.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 simplest ways would be:

- The built-in:

  `sum(datos)`
- A reduction:

  `reduce(operator.add, datos)`

  This way essentially inserts the addition operator between each element of the list, which ends up summing it.

You could also do the manual way as shown by @pegla, but that's rarely necessary.

Comment: well but actually I don't want to sum up all the elements just from cero to seven since eight nine and more than that I don't need it, I am reading data over serial

Comment: @Chrisgates Oh, well then the answer you accepted is wrong too, since it will sum the entire list aswell. I'll delete this in a bit.